# What does the Ampersand do in a SQL where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, nice

I'm trying to figure this query out and can't figure out how it relates:

```
Where   iInteractionOpenReasonID & 16 = 0
```

Possible values for iInteractionOpenReasonID should be:

```
0 Unknown
1 Normal Start
2 Normal End
4 Transfer Start
8 Transfer End
16 Conference
32 Inter Queue
64 Networking
128 Segment
256 Compound
512 Block
1024 Clip Recording
```

I'm seeing values of 129 and 145 (which aren't in the list) and that where clause filters out the 145...I'm confused

Comment: Yep, looks like it. When I searched I couldn't find anything but then again I didn't know you could use & in an actual search so I was typing it out

Answer (score 3):

"The & bitwise operator performs a bitwise logical AND between the two expressions, taking each corresponding bit for both expressions. The bits in the result are set to 1 if and only if both bits (for the current bit being resolved) in the input expressions have a value of 1; otherwise, the bit in the result is set to 0."

Try looking at the msdn doucmentation here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx

Comment: I'm either more confused or less confused. Let's see
145 is Binary 10010001
129 is Binary 10000001
16 is Binary 10000

So if my clause says
Where   iInteractionOpenReasonID & 16 = 0

and iInteractionOpenReasonID = 129 then the result would be 1 because the first 5 digits of 10000001 are 10000
and iInteractionOpenReasonID = 145 then the result would be 0 because 10010001 does not contain 10000

Comment: Sorry it flubbed up the formatting

Comment: @TalkingScientist I'm afraid I can't explain it any better than showdev did above with his link.